# Click in row in listview

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, onitemclicklistener

I have the following problem. I show myself a list and I have implemented a click on an item in the list. I would like items replaced with string. My list shows name and id. I would like to see how to click eg in 10 lines where id put 50 it will go to the new class and there I would need to retrieve that string which would be 50 from the previous class and globally declare. Maybe it will show more or less:

This is my click in the position:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    DevicesList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    new GetDevices().execute();
    button2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    idbudynku = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Buildings.this, DevicesList,
            R.layout.list_item3, new String[]{"name", "id"},
            new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.id});

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                          int position, long id) {
                                      if (position == 0) {
                                          Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Buildings_Devices.class);
                                          startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
```

Here we have an int position that I would like to replace with the string that I am downloading:

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray buildings = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

                for (int i = 0; i < buildings.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = buildings.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");

                            HashMap<String, String> building = new HashMap<>();

                    building.put("id", id);
                    building.put("name", name);

                            DevicesList.add(building);

                        }

            } catch ...
```

And now he wants to not read me after position only after the value of String id eg 50. Then he will go to the new class and there you have to keep the information which string value was downloaded so I could continue to use that value